# Ошибка при использовании библиотеки react-native-video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, видео, react-native, native

Хочу использовать видео в react native
Установил react-native-video, подключил библиотеку, создал элемент Video, вписал в uri ссылку на видео поставил style={styles.backgroundVideo} и выскакивает ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of null

Весь интернет обыскал и не нашёл решения.
Может тут хоть кто поможет

###### Полная ошибка:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of null

This error is located at:
    in Video (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes`
```

###### Полный код:

```js
import Video from "react-native-video";
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="auto"/>
        <Video source={{uri:'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4'}}
            style={styles.backgroundVideo}/>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#F0EFEC',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте советы из [ответов на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60018247/8489602).

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй `http` на `https` - в ios и androin `http` не работает

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, почему?

Comment: если вы увеерны, что это единственное и достаточное условие для решения описанной проблемы, то всё в порядке. в чём есть сомнения: в вопросе ведь вообще не упоминается, что не работает именно на смартфонах.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Не уверен на 100% что мой ответ правильный, но уверен что никакое видео не будет работать на любых системах android или ios пока не будет `https`. Не важно смартфон это или что-то другое.